# Using NSPrintOperation in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, printing, interface-builder

I'm writing a document based Mac OSX application, and I'm reading a tutorial that talks about using the NSPrintOperation (by default, pressing print in my application right now gives the error:

```
   printOperationWithSettings:error: is a subclass responsibility but has not been overridden.
```

So I'm told to use the following:

```
    - (NSPrintOperation *)printOperationWithSettings:(NSDictionary *)ps error:(NSError **)e;
{
    NSPrintInfo *printInfo = [self printInfo];
    NSPrintOperation *printOp = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:MyView
                                                               printInfo:printInfo];
    return printOp;
```

(where **MyView** is the name of the view i want printed. My question is where do i name that view? In Interface Builder? I tried 'self' and that threw an error. I'm still learning cocoa so I'm confused. The instances in Interface Builder are just NSView's and are named View (not unique). Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your document's .h file, add the following:

```
@interface MyDocument : NSDocument {
    IBOutlet NSView      *myView;
}

@end
```

(If you actually have a custom subclass of an `NSView`, or the view you intend on printing is a more particular kind of view (for example, `NSTableView`), you would probably change the type to be that type instead of the generic `NSView`).

Then, in Interface Builder, in the nib file, you will most likely Control-drag from the "File's owner" object to the view you intend to print. When you see the view highlighted, and let go, you should get a popup menu where you can choose `myView`. Now you've hooked up the wires, so to speak, so you can have a reference to that particular view in the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you so much let me see how this goes!

Comment: It's giving me: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2000f75a0

Comment: I have it connected to a textView. Is that appropriate?